# PHP Regex Match of Anchor Tag

Tags: php, html, regex, string, split

I am trying to use REGEX to split a string apart while maintaining the delimeters. I wish to split a very large and unpredictable string apart via anchor tags. I am using HTML tidy to ensure the tags are correct, however anything could come before or after the anchor tag I wish to match.

```
*PRECEDING-ANYTHING*<a *ANYTHING*>*ANYTHING*</a>*PROCEDING-ANYTHING*
*PRECEDING-ANYTHING*<a *ANYTHING*>*ANYTHING*</a>*PROCEDING-ANYTHING*
```

where the href URL could be anything and additional attributes such as 'target' could also be anything.

I've done a lot of searching and testing and either I am doing something wrong or the other answers on Stack Overflow do not apply.

Using

```
$parts= preg_split($pattern, $textWithAnchors, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
```

I was hoping to have $parts be similar to the following.

```
parts[0] is equal to *PRECEDING-ANYTHING*
parts[1] is equal to <a *ANYTHING*>*ANYTHING*</a>
and so forth
```

It is important that the regular expression capture the entire anchor tags and everything inside.

I would very much appreciate any help, I'm asking specifically for a regular expression that will accomplish this in PHP. I am aware that there are HTML parsers however, using REGEX is optimal in this situation. Maybe it will be a learning experiance though.

Comment: Please look at the `DOMDocument` class, it's much more hands-on and supports loading partial code. You could easily load one of your lines and let it find all `a`-tags.

Comment: See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Show some of the regexen you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have done a lot of reading on those other methods and at the moment to the best of my knowledge regular expressions are still the best way to complete this task. I have seen this sort of operation successfully done with PHP regular expressions before and with to complete it via regex.

I understand that this may be a dirty way of doing it, but in that case it will be a learning experiance.

Also, I wanted to point out that the example I used above are not just lines, the *ANYTHING* text could be paragraphs, other HTML, chars, line breaks etc.

Comment: You really dont want to use regular expressions for this. But here goes /.*(<a.*</a>).*/i

Comment: If it isn't too much work, I would appreciate a simple answer of what regular expression pattern would match the entire anchor tag.

You may all then sit back and laugh at me as I attempt to get it to work if that helps ;p

Comment: Edit, I've tried '/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/s' and '/<a[^>]+>/i' and '#<a(.*?)a>#'

and a few others I will pull up.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry if I came off arrogant or pushy. I truly do appreciate the help, in a few minutes I got the answer. Cheers

Comment: Also for future reference,  /.*(<a.*</a>).*/i should be  /.*(<a.*<\/a>).*/i otherwise an unkown modifier error occurs in PHP.

Comment: make the `a.*` an `a.*?` too

Answer (score 1):

Using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` won't help you, because that returns text captured in group 1 of the delimiter regex as a *separate element*, but you want the delimiters to be *included* with the elements.

To specify delimiters that *don't* consume input, use regex *look arounds*.
This code does the job:

```
$parts= preg_split('/(?=<a)|(?<=\/a>)/', $textWithAnchors);
```

It's splitting using a look-ahead for the open tag, an da look behind for the closing tag.

See a [live demo](http://codepad.org/1NWh1Y9f) of this code splitting your example as required.